# Appending td's back into a table from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, append

I have a table that has had some java applied to it to arrange the td's into the correct order. Unfortunately it has now moved those td's from outside the table into a div. This is representative of how the table now looks:

```
<div id="attributeInputs">
  <table class="js-grid">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th class="js-col1"></th> 
   <th class="js-col2" colspan="8"></th>
   </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="1"></th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">2XL</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">3XL</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">4XL</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">LG</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">ME</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">SM</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">XL</th>
        <th class="js-rowtitleX">XS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="js-rowtitleY">Light Stonewash</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="js-rowtitleY">Stonewash</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="js-rowtitleY">White</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <td class="js-gridBlock js-Low_stock" data-attvalue1="XS" data-attvalue2="White" id="gridBlock_D14ADA4C-0BB5-11E6-812F-DE885FFE5FF7"><div class="js-gridImage"><div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox24"><span>Low stock</span></div></div></td>

    <td class="js-gridBlock js-Low_stock" data-attvalue1="XS" data-attvalue2="Stonewash" id="gridBlock_D14ADA4C-0BB5-11E6-812F-DE885FFE5FF7"><div class="js-gridImage"><div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox16"><span>Low stock</span></div></div></td>`

    <td class="js-gridBlock js-Low_stock" data-attvalue1="XS" data-attvalue2="Light Stonewash" id="gridBlock_D14ADA4C-0BB5-11E6-812F-DE885FFE5FF7"><div class="js-gridImage"><div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox8"><span>Low stock</span></div></div></td>

    <td class="js-gridBlock js-In_stock" data-attvalue1="SM" data-attvalue2="White" id="gridBlock_D14ADA4C-0BB5-11E6-812F-DE885FFE5FF7"><div class="js-gridImage"><div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox22"><span>In stock</span></div></div></td>

    <td class="js-gridBlock js-In_stock" data-attvalue1="SM" data-attvalue2="Light Stonewash" id="gridBlock_D14ADA4C-0BB5-11E6-812F-DE885FFE5FF7"><div class="js-gridImage"><div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox6"><span>In stock</span></div></div></td>

    <td class="js-gridBlock js-In_stock" data-attvalue1="SM" data-attvalue2="Stonewash" id="gridBlock_D14ADA4C-0BB5-11E6-812F-DE885FFE5FF7"><div class="js-gridImage"><div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox14"><span>In stock</span></div></div></td>
    </div>
```

My goal is to try and get the respective td's back into the appropriate js-rowtitleY's.

I have tried different variations of the below, just to attempt to get the td's back into the actual table but as you can probably tell my jQuery knowledge is lacking a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     if ($("#attributeInputs").data('td[data-attvalue2="Black"]')){
        $('td[data-attvalue2="White"]').appendTo('.js-grid th');
        };
});
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the general direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to get access TD element without having access to table & Tr elements. I tried to get the hold of accessing Td element using querySelectorAll, getElementById, $([Attribute=value]) it did not work. if you can change TD to some other element like div, then we can get it back to alignment.